# How can I find out the relationship between two columns in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view defined in SQL Server database and it has two columns A and B, both of which have the type of INT. I want to find out the relationship between these two, `1 to 1` or `1 to many` or `many to many`. Is there a SQL statement I can use to find out?

For the relationship, it means for a given value of A, how many values of B maps to this value. If there is only one value, then it is 1 to 1 mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have no `NULL` values:

```
select (case when count(*) = count(distinct a) and
                  count(*) = count(distinct b)
             then '1-1'
             when count(*) = count(distinct a) or
                  count(*) = count(distinct b)
             then '1-many'
             else 'many-many'
        end)
from t;
```

Note:  This does not distinguish between 1-many for a-->b or b-->a.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CTE`s to generate `COUNT`s of how many distinct `A` values were associated with each `B` value and vice versa, then take the `MAX` of those values to determine if the relationship is 1 or many on each side. For example:

```
WITH CTEA AS (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B) ac
  FROM t
  GROUP BY A
),
CTEB AS (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A) bc
  FROM t
  GROUP BY B
)
SELECT CONCAT(
         CASE WHEN MAX(bc) = 1 THEN '1' ELSE 'many' END,
         ' to ',
         CASE WHEN MAX(ac) = 1 THEN '1' ELSE 'many' END
       ) AS [A to B]
FROM CTEA
CROSS JOIN CTEB
```

Note that any time a relationship is listed as `1`, it may actually be `many` but just not showing that because of limited data in the table.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=c84fad1ea8544f182e842bb0b4c83a13)

Comment: I believe the op is trying to get the relationship between a and b. if there are records like this (a,b) -->(1,100)(1,100) it would show up  as many to many.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph good point And of course you can't use `DISTINCT` with `OVER`... so that makes it a lot messier, but I've corrected the query and demo.

Answer (score 0):

You would use count and group by to get this information.

--This would give you count of values of b which map to every values of a. If there is at least one row with a count give you a value greater than 1 it means the mapping between a and b is one to many.

```
select a,count( distinct b)
  from table
group by a
```

If all of the rows have the values equal to one for all of the elements in a then the mapping is one-one

A caveat , null in b would be ignored in count expressions. ie because null and another null is not equivalent